# Enum returning statement

Tags: java, interface, enums

What if I have an interface  and the interface has inside it a method that return a type Enumerator, in the classes that implement the interface how should I write the return statement?
like:

```
public enum Day 
{
    Saturday,Sunday....
}

public interface blabla 
{  
    public Day getDay(); 
}

public class blabla2 implements blabla 
{ 
    public Day getDay() 
    { 
        return ???? what should I write here ?
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: Have a look at the `Enumeration` interface which provides a way to iterate over the elements of a potentially dynamic collection/enumeration. Enums on the other hand are a built-in language feature that which describe a more or less static enumeration. The two are related, but they are different and server different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> return ???? what should I write here ?

Well, it depends on how you determine the day to return, but if the day is fixed, you could write

```
public Day getDay() 
{ 
  return Sunday; //or Day.Sunday depending on your imports and package
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the whatever `Day` is appropriate.

In the code below, I return the enum value for Saturday.

```
    public enum Day 
    {
        Saturday,Sunday;
    }

    public interface blabla 
    {  
        public Day getDay(); 
    }

    public class blabla2 implements blabla 
    { 
        public Day getDay() 
        { 
            return Day.Saturday;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration (Enum) its a type/structure of data that represents a limited group of possible values

[JavaDoc Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Also Enumeration (Interface) is an interface to make enumerations of collections of objects

[Java Doc Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

If "Enum" the returning value can be any of the Enum set.

```
public enum Day {
    Saturday,
    Sunday
    ...
}

public Day getDay()  { 
    return Day.Saturday;
}
```